# Is it possible to create a JSF2 session managed bean inside a filter?

Tags: jsf-2, servlet-filters, cas

I would like to create and populate a JSF2 session bean inside a filter.
The use case is the following:

- 1) the user authenticate using CAS
- 2) CAS server populate the attributes of the principal and in one
  attribute there is the user group in LDAP/AD (this info will be used
  to get access grant to the user)
- 3) a filter is called only when the user is authenticated and
  extracts the group info from the principal
- 4) a session bean is used to contain the other principal attributes
  (and other info gathered from a DB using those attributes)
- 5) if the session bean already exists for that user, nothing has to
  be done
- 6) if the session bean does not exists, it should be created (in the
  filter I guess) and populated
- 7) the filter allows the user to access the web page which contains
  all the info in the session bean.

Is that possible?
I know that when the session bean is created it is attached as an attribute to the http session, so it is easy to access to it in a filter, but I don't know if it is possible to create the session bean from the filter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We did exactly the same (OpenID authentication) without creating session bean by hand. All you need, is to wrap all the auth tokens, id's, roles and other stuff in a single serializable class (let it be `UserAuthInfo`) and store an instance of this class in session map after authentication. Later on, in a regular session bean, you check the presence of this object in a session map, initialize all the necessary data, read DB, do other things and optionally remove `UserAuthInfo` instance from session map.

Comment: OK, thanks. In this way there is no need to handle the managedBean inside the filter!